# Editing Data Extension Records in Contact Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, contactbuilder

I am baffled by this feature. Many times I am able to edit individual data extension records under Contact Builder and many times I am not.

Is there a rule that governs that?

Comment: In my MC account i noticed that previously i was not able to edit the data extension records but now i can and on my side nobody other then me is changing the permission or anything.So i believe they are working on the MC features and improving it so sometimes we hit the bug or something and it may not be the persistent issue.

Comment: I've never seen this behavior. You can't edit the primary key in a Data Extension, but you should be able to edit other fields in a record. Also, you will need to ensure that the record fields you are editing match the length requirement defined for the field and if they are required fields, you would need values for them. What error message do you get?

Comment: Can you add fields to a data extension once it has a relationship in contact builder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are likely experiencing this because you are trying to alter a Data Extension that isn't compatible. These are the restrictions I've noticed that don't allow you to edit individual records:

- No Primary Key
- Filtered Data Extension
- Synchronized Data Extension

It can be a bit harder to notice which type of Data Extension it is with the Contact Builder interface.

Comment: Hello Anon, so what you are saying is - If my data extension doesn't have a primary key, I will not be able to edit individual records under contact builder?
And similarly for other aforementioned constraints..

Comment: Yes that appears to be the case. This also applies to removing single records, and I guess searching for records too - as searching is done by Primary Key it will alwats return all records.

There doesn't appear to be official documentation (that I can find at least), but on all instances I've seen this is the case.

Comment: Thanks Anon! Another condition is that it should not be a part of any Journey.